# Array to Stream in Delphi 10.4

Tags: arrays, delphi

How can i save and load an '**Array[0..9] of TJpegImage**' to a **MemoryStream**.
There are many samples to save one Image to a Stream but no one save an Array.
I need it to save the Stream to a Database Blob field and later load the BlobField back to my Array.
All Images in the Array has the same Size.
Maybe a Stream of TByte can do this ?
But how to convert a TByte-Stream back to an Array?

Update:
Thank you very much MBo for your example.
I tried to use it and get some Problems.
I use a Paintbox to Draw the Picture and get an access violation at 0x0062b9ab:read of address 0x000....

This is the Code i try:

unit PicToMemStream;
interface

uses
Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.Imaging.jpeg, Vcl.ExtCtrls;

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Image1: TImage;
    PaintBox: TPaintBox;
  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}


var
  ms, temp: TMemoryStream;
  jps: array of TJpegImage;
  i, n, sz: Integer;
  ProgPath: String;
begin
  ProgPath := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName);
  n := 3;
  SetLength(jps, n);
  ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
  temp := TMemoryStream.Create;

  for i := 0 to n - 1 do
  begin
    jps[i] := TJpegImage.Create;
    jps[i].LoadFromFile(Format(ProgPath + '%s.jpg', [Chr(Ord('a') + i)]));
    // in my case loads files a.jpg, b.jpg, c.jpg
  end;

  // Save Pictures to Stream and later in BlobField (100kByte)
  try
    ms.Write(n, SizeOf(n));
    for i := 0 to n - 1 do
    begin

      temp.Clear;
      // Save Image Data first here
      jps[i].SaveToStream(temp); // jpeg data here

      sz := temp.Size;
      // Save length second here
      ms.Write(sz, SizeOf(sz)); // size of image

      temp.Position := 0;
      ms.CopyFrom(temp, sz); // image data to final destination
    end;

    ms.SaveToFile(ProgPath + 'base.dat'); // for control // later here Write Data to BLob


    // Read Picture and show it in a Paintbox or Image
    // revert to empty stream
    ms.Clear;
    ms.LoadFromFile(ProgPath + 'base.dat'); // load from "base" // later here Read Data from Blob

    ms.Read(n, SizeOf(n));
    // here some actions to setup array

    for i := 0 to n - 1 do // Read 3 times a picture
    begin
      ms.Read(sz, SizeOf(sz)); // Read Lenth of Picturedata first

      temp.Clear; // Read Picturedata in jps[i]
      temp.CopyFrom(ms, sz);
      temp.Position := 0;
      jps[i].LoadFromStream(temp);

      Form1.PaintBox.Canvas.Draw(0, 0, jps[i]); // Show Picture with  Error
      //Form1.Image1.Picture.Bitmap.LoadFromStream(temp);
      Sleep(2000); // To see the Picture for 2 seconds (Test)
    end;

  finally
    ms.Free;
    temp.Free;
    for i := 0 to n - 1 do
        jps[i].Free;
  end;
end.
```

Update2:
I put the code in a ButtomClick procedure and change:

```
  temp.Position := 0;
  jps[i].LoadFromStream(temp);

  Form1.PaintBox.Canvas.Draw(0, 0, jps[i]);  // Show Picture in Paintbox
  Form1.Image1.Picture.Assign(jps[i]); // Show Picture in TImage
  Application.ProcessMessages;
  Sleep(500); // To see the Picture for 2 seconds (Test)
end;
```

I will also test the other Ideas with using Master-Detail Table or TFDMemTable or Encoding to Text, to see what is the best for me.
Thanks to all Helpers.

Comment: Iterate the array and write each element to the stream.

Comment: Why would you want to have multiple images saved in same database field? Why not use relational connection to another database table which you use only for storing images. This way you allow yourself to have any number of images connected to your main record. Also you avoid one huge drawback of your approach and that is that in your approach if you want to retrieve just one of those images you need to retrieve the contents of the whole blob field first (all images at once). This can greatly increase data traffic between your client and the database.

Comment: @SilverWarior Yes i thought about this but i think the overhead for this is more than the method with using a stream. I try to minimize the size of the database.

Comment: Why do you think that? In order to create relational database connection you only need common identifier in both database tables. I'm guessing that in your record you already have some User_ID field. You could use this field for creating the relational connection. This means that the records in new table for storing picture will have two fields One for storing User_ID and another blob field for storing image data. Now I'm guessing that you are likely storing your User_ID as standard integer field which is 32 bit integer field or 4 bytes of data. ...

Comment: ... This means that by using relational connections you will increase your database size by four bytes for each picture. Not to much of a overhead on the database side is it. What about your approach? If you use **MBo** suggestion you are storing one 32 bit integer for image count and one additional 32 integer for storing the size of each image. That is just four bytes more for each user than in my suggestion. Doesn't seem much worse on the database size does it. ...

Comment: ... But let us now take a look at impact of such solutions on client size. If you go with relational tables this has almost no impact on the client side. Because now client can simply request to receive data for nth image that belongs to certain user and the database only sends data for that specific image to the client. But with your approach the database will always send data for all stored images from a specific user. And then you need to process all that data in order to retrieve specific image out from it. So a lot more traffic between database and client application ...

Comment: .. And you also have a lot more processing needed in client application. This means that your solution while it doesn't have much overhead on the database side except for a lot more traffic it has a huge overhead on your client side where you are doing bunch of processing. Now imagine your user stored 40 4K images in the database where each image is about 20 MB in size. This means that with your solution you would not be storing 400 MB in this one blob field. And in order to show just one of those pictures you will have to retrieve all 400 MB of data from the database. ...

Comment: ... If this is a local database this might not have much impact but if this is a networked database receiving this 400 MB of data will take some time. Also note that you will have to store all these 400 MB into memory on your client side before you would even begin any processing for retrieving specific image out from the collection of all images stored in that blob field. This is a **huge** overhead that could greatly increase memory requirements of your application.

Comment: As for **Germán Balbi** suggestion for encoding the image data into Base64 encoding format. The purpose of Base64 encoding is to convert unreadable binary data into readable string. Since there are more unreadable characters in most binary files that they are readable character this means that Base64 encoded string is almost always larger than the original binary data. While it depends on the contents of the binary data but it isn't unusual for Base64 encoded string to be even 30% larger than the original binary data.

Comment: @SilverWarior You are right to say if i have to use an integer for every Picture in the Stream i can also use an separate ID for a MasterDetail Connection. To work with MasterDetail Database Action is easier to work, because i firstly need only one Picture to show and the other pictures are only needed if the user click the Video-Button. But did not load the Database Client the whole Detail Table when i start the SQL Query ? (My Pictures are all ~100kBytes large and i need 120 Pictures per SubID where a Video is in the Mainrecord, the main record has ~100 Datarecords with one ore 120 Pictures)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`All Images in the Array has the same Size` - perhaps dimensions (width/height) are the same, but size of jpeg image in bytes varies depending on picture and compression. So I assume you need to store both image data and data size.

Possible approach:

- write integer value - length of array - to memory stream `ms`
- for every array element save it to temporary memory stream `temp_ms`
- write integer value `sz = ms.size` to main memory stream `ms`
- reset `temp_ms.Position` to 0
- copy (`CopyFrom`) `sz` bytes from `temp_ms` to `ms`
- clear `temp_ms`
- repeat for all array elements

Now `ms` contents looks like:

```
10        14212   FFD8....D9     31234   FFD8....D9   
10 images 
         1st image size
                   1st image contents 
                                 2nd image size
                                         2nd image contents
```

To retrieve image, perform reverse actions:

- reset `ms` position (if needed)
- read number of images `n` from `ms`
- set arrray size (if array is dynamic)
- `n` times:
- read size of image `sz`
- copy `sz` bytes to `temp_ms`
- reset `temp_ms.Position`
- load `array[i]` from `temp_ms`

working example:

```
var
  ms, temp: TMemoryStream;
  jps: array of TJpegImage;
  i, n, sz: Integer;
begin
  n := 3;
  SetLength(jps, n);
  ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
  temp := TMemoryStream.Create;

  for i := 0 to n - 1 do begin
    jps[i] := TJpegImage.Create;
    jps[i].LoadFromFile(Format('h:\%s.jpg', [Chr(Ord('a') + i)]));
    //in my case loads files a.jpg, b.jpg, c.jpg
  end;

  try
    ms.Write(n, SizeOf(n));
    for i :=0 to n - 1 do begin

      temp.Clear;
      jps[i].SaveToStream(temp); //jpeg data here

      sz := temp.Size;
      ms.Write(sz, SizeOf(sz));   //size of image

      temp.Position := 0;
      ms.CopyFrom(temp, sz);     //image data to final destination
    end;

    ms.SaveToFile('h:\base.dat');  //for control

    //revert to empty stream
    ms.Clear;
    ms.LoadFromFile('h:\base.dat');  //load from "base"

    ms.Read(n, SizeOf(n));
    //here some actions to setup array

    for i :=0 to n - 1 do begin

      ms.Read(sz, SizeOf(sz));

      temp.Clear;
      temp.CopyFrom(ms, sz);
      temp.Position := 0;
      jps[i].LoadFromStream(temp);

      Canvas.Draw(i * 200, 0, jps[i]); //control shot
    end;

  finally
    ms.Free;
    temp.Free;
    for i := 0 to n - 1 do
       jps[i].Free;
  end;
```

Comment: Thats correct MBo, the Size of the Images varies because they are compressed.
I did not think about this. Now i have to find the syntax for MemoryStreams to do that. Never worked with MemoryStreams.

Comment: You can write without the temporary memory stream if you seek and write the mengths after writing each stream

Comment: @David Heffernan If you know a simpler way as MBo did lets see some Code

Comment: I don't really want to write any code here. It's not hard. Just seek back o ve you know the length.

Comment: @Gerrys This is really simple code. Where are you executing this code? Seems before Form and controls creation. Put a Button on the form and move the code into Button.OnClick handler

Comment: @MBo OMG I was so focused on the Code that i forgot the simplest Thing. I have learned very much about Streams with this code. Your Code "ms.Write(n, SizeOf(n));" was something i do not know how to do it, to save a Integer. Thank you so much MBo for your Help with this code.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a TFDMemTable?

Another option can be, TStringList using System.NetEncoding.TNetEncoding.Base64 encoding
since TStringList is very much like a superpowered vector

Comment: Yes i want to use a TFDMemtable after selecting my PictureRecords from the Database. There are, lets say 100 records, for one selected UserID that i have to show in a Grid. When the user run to that Grid the first Picture is shown in te Paintbox or Image. Some Record has only one Picture and some has 20 Pictures. The user can decide later to show the Pictures in a loop. In a Field in the record there is defined if there only is one Picture or a Video.

Comment: okay.  I assume you are talking about a multi image file.  tiff dcom gif.  etc.  If so, these have an index and you will only have to save that index to later access that image directly.